# Crawled Properties - DateTime only showing Date and not Time

Tags: 2010, crawled-property

I've created a metadata property called `CalendarEventDate`.
It is mapped to "ows_EventDate (DateTime)" or something like that.

I did a full crawl afterwards and when I checked the raw XML, I found that it only returned the *Date* portion of *Date and Time*.
[image]

What's worse is that it is displaying the **wrong** date!
Here's the correct datetime from the list item:
[image]

What should I do so that the XML returns the full *Date and Time* or at least the correct *Date*?

---

<sub>**Update**</sub>

I guess as a workaround, I could create calculated fields that store the Date and Time values, but I don't want to be adding extra fields if possible.

Answer (score 4):

[DateFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.webcontrols.searchresultsbasewebpart.dateformat.aspx) property is used for specifying the date and time formatting for the [CoreResultsWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms497469.aspx) web part.

By default search results in the web part are displayed in [DateOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms414006) format.

### Usage

> This property could **not** be specified using web part editor, so please
>   consider another options for specifying it value, for example
>   SharePoint Designer or Export/Import web part.

For example, after specifying this property value to `DateTime`:

```
<property name="DateFormat" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPDateFormat, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">DateTime</property>
```

`calendareventdate` property would be displayed like this:

```
<calendareventdate>2/12/2013 12:58 PM</calendareventdate>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting both the Date and Time now, but it's still the wrong date for some reason: `<calendareventdate>24/12/2013 5:00 PM</calendareventdate>`. It should be `25/12/2013 12:00 AM`. I've checked other items and the same is true (e.g. I'm getting `<calendareventdate>04/08/2013 6:00 PM</calendareventdate>` for what is supposed to be `05/08/2013 12:00 AM`). It looks to me that anything set to `Month X, YYYY 12:00 AM` is returned as `Month (X-1), YYYY (5 or 6) PM`. If the time is actually set to something other than `12:00 AM`, it displays correctly.

Comment: It seems the "All Day Event" flag is what is causing the problem here. When it is unchecked, the date and time are displayed correctly. Would you happen to know the fix for this?

Comment: Indeed, most likely it is related with All Day Event flag. When this flag is set, the date is returned in GMT time and not the current time (!) I'm a little bit surprised since was thinking that this issue has been resolved by MS. More details: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/27ab0bb0-245b-46ca-9f87-c0eb043653ef/date-formatting-in-calendars-returns-wrong-day

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint stores date value in UTC format. While rendering the data SharePoint converts it to local time and displays it correctly.

In your case the UTC date value is returned from Search. While displaying the data you should change it to local time (By customizing the XSLT etc.)

http://itblog.wolthaus.net/2011/09/sharepoint-stores-dates-in-utc-time/

For changing the display format you can use `FormatDate` option

```
ddwrt:FormatDate(@ArticleStartDate, 2057, 2)
```

That will display date in mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM AM/PM format.

Comment: I think that this has nothing to do with format, OP mentioned **raw xml** format

Comment: I have misread the question. I think time for coffee break :)